# I'm having trouble using the Windows key on my keyboard. What can I do to troubleshoot and enable the key?

Tags: windows, key, disable

Normally when you use a keyboard there is a windows key that lets you open the windows menu or does a lot of shortcut. But my windows key is not responding.

I tried pressing Fn + windows & Fn + F12 and tried changing the No_win key in the regedit app (Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies)